# Argparse with OR logic on arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I am coding an argument parser for my script:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My parser.')
parser.add_argument('path',
                    type=str)
parser.add_argument('-a', 
                    '--all',
                    action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-t', 
                    '--type',
                    type=str)
parser.add_argument('-d', 
                    '--date',
                    type=str)
```

This is the logic I want to implement:

- `path`: must be provided always.
- `--all`: if it is provided, the `--type` and `--date` should not appear.
- `--type` and `--date`: must be provided only if the `--all` flag is not introduced.

The command would look something like this:

```
python myscript.py mypath [-a] OR [-t mytype -d mydate]
```

How can I implement this logic?

Comment: Are you talking about the logic of only using --all if --all is written or to print the usage message correct? https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#usage

Comment: About how to implement the logic of using one of `--all` OR `--type mytype --date mydate` @mama

Comment: `argparse` provides an `xor`, but it's flat - no any/all for groups within that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description='My parser.')

parser.add_argument('path',
                    type=str)
parser.add_argument('-a', 
                    '--all',
                    action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-t', 
                    '--type',
                    type=str)
parser.add_argument('-d', 
                    '--date',
                    type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.all:
    print('all argument flow')
else: 
    if not args.type or not args.date:
        print('you need to put either all or specify both type and date')
    else:
        print(args.type, args.date)

print('and',args.path)
```

Comment: That's a hard-coding way of doing it for sure, but I was looking for an option using the `argsparse` native parameters and modules. That way the library will take care of printing the messages helping the user with a proper format and logic.

Comment: The `print` can be replaced with `parser.error(your_message)`, to get the usage along with the message.  But you'll have to supply your own `usage` when initialling the parser, using what ever notation you hope to convey your logic.  `argparse` can only implement a simple mutually_exclusive_group logic.

Comment: @Luiscri If the library would take care of this kind of logic then it would become bloated. - you have to do it yourself :D